# openlayers how render rectangular pixels - TileLayer COG

Tags: render, openlayers, pixel, geotiff

I have COG geotiff which I would like to render on map. I use fot this:

```
   const source = new GeoTIFF({
    normalize: false,
    sources: [
        {
            url: "raster.tif",

        },
    ],
})


const layer = new TileLayer({
    source: source,
    style: {
        color: mapStyleStandardColor(0),
        opacity: 1,
    },
})
```

The file is rendered on map but pixels are not squers. I woild like to have all pixels sharpe and rectangular. How to achive that?

actual rendered:
[image: actual_rendered]

desire render:
[image: desire_render]

Comment: `interpolate: false` in the GeoTIFF options will prevent interpolation when overzooming